# grub on efi loads kernel but will not boot it

Tags: grub, uefi

```
insmod normal
insmod btrfs
insmod part_gpt

set root=(hd0,2) 

menuentry 'Ubuntu' {
        linux /boot/vmlinuz root=/dev/sda2 ro
        initrd /boot/core.gz
        boot
}
```

Hi, I am learning how to manually make EFI boot setup!

I got some good progress, I have created EFI partition, then created bootloader with `grub-mkimage`, put it into EFI/BOOT, then created `grub.cfg`, then I downloaded a kernel and ramdisk from TinyCore and put these two files in `(hd0,2)`.

Now I can load `qemu` and get into `Grub` where I can load `linux /vmlinuz` it seems to load file, it can see files with `ls` as well. But after it seems all I need is to type `boot` and see kernel loading nothing happens, I just type `boot` and it hangs, and all I can do is reboot.

I understand that at this stage I will pobably not be able to successfully boot but at least I expect the boot starting, having some messages from the kernel about IRQ setups, devices detected etc.

What could be my next step?

Qemu command line:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -display sdl -vga std -accel kvm -m 8000 \
    -drive format=raw,file=/dev/sda -bios /mnt/boot.flash -smp 2
```

Comment: What is the exact `qemu` command line you're using? And it seems to me that TinyCore appears to be BIOS-only; I see no evidence that it would support UEFI boot at all. But if you have found a TinyCore kernel that is specified to be UEFI-compatible, then you know more about it than me...

Comment: ```qemu-system-x86_64 -display sdl -vga std -accel kvm -m 8000 -drive format=raw,file=/dev/sda -bios /mnt/boot.flash -smp 2```

Comment: @telcoM I also thought that TinyCore may not support EFI so I replaced it with Puppy, interestingly when I got completely tired after an entire day trying with QEMU I just gave it a try on real hardware and it loaded! So I think I can now be sure that my EFI setup is correct which is exciting to know given how difficult it was to get through all the alien terminology for me! But I still cannot figure booting in QEMU, it still hangs.

Answer (score 1):

What is your `/mnt/boot.flash` file?

When booting UEFI, it should probably be something like `/usr/share/ovmf/OVMF.fd` or `/usr/share/qemu/OVMF.fd`, which might be already available on your host system, or possibly installable in a package named `ovmf` or something similar.

See: https://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2021/04/how-to-boot-uefi-on-qemu.html

To make your UEFI NVRAM boot variables persist in your virtual machine, you might also want to use the `-pflash` option:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -display sdl -vga std -accel kvm -m 8000 \
    -drive format=raw,file=/dev/sda -bios /usr/share/ovmf/OVMF.fd \
    -pflash /some/writeable/location/OVMF_VARS.fd -smp 2
```

With luck, you might have an example `OVMF_VARS.fd` file included among the files installed by the `ovmf` package, but if not, you might try creating an empty file of about 528K or so, and using that, on the assumption that the UEFI firmware will be able to initialize the variable storage automatically if it's not properly initialized.

See: https://joonas.fi/2021/02/uefi-pc-boot-process-and-uefi-with-qemu/

Comment: Yes, `boot.flash` was created by `cp /usr/share/ovmf/OVMF.fd boot.flash`. I have read somewhere that QEMU could modify the file to store variables in it.

Comment: I can see TianoCore logo when I start QEMU.

Comment: There should be a separate file for NVRAM variable storage; the requirement to modify the `-bios` file would be kind of silly. See my edit.